# Why can't I switch an enum in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, enums, switch-statement

I can't seem to figure out how I should use a switch statement with my custom typedef enum. Xcode tells this error:

> Statement requires expression of integer type (MyEnum *) is invalid.

this is my enum declared over the @interface in my header

```
typedef enum {
  A, B, C, D, E, F, G,
  Ab, Bb, Db, Eb, Gb,
  CSharp, DSharp, FSharp, GSharp
} Tones;
```

this is my property:
`@property(nonatomic) Tones *tone;`

and this is my function to get the string value of the enum

```
- (NSString *)stringValue {

  switch (self.tone) {
    case GSharp:
      return @"G#";
    ...
  } 
}
```

Comment: You are doing your switch on a pointer...

Comment: Don't declare `Tones *tone` it should be `Tones tone` - no asterisk it's not a pointer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An enum has literal values (basically named integers), not object pointers. Thus it should be:

```
@property(nonatomic) Tones tone;
```